# Using spread operator in a loop with object literals in javascript

Tags: javascript, arguments

I have generated arrays from an ajax response.
An example of an array is

```
var prds = ["248", "NORFLOX 200 MG", "22"]
```

I have checked the array by `Array.isArray()` method and the response is true.

In the same loop i pass the above array as an argument in the onclick event function like so...

```
str += `<li onclick=loadProductEditForm(${prds})>${productsj[i]['medicine_name']}<li>';
```

When i use the function `loadProductEditForm(array)` it does not work and give me this error in the console....

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list.

I have tried this too...

```
str += `<li onclick=loadProductEditForm(...${prds})>${productsj[i]['medicine_name']}<li>';
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does your `loadProductEditForm()` function looks like? and why you need to pass param to it like `...prds`?

Comment: That's why you should not use inline html event handlers. Use a closure and install it properly on the element using DOM methods.

Comment: function loadProductEditForm(array) {alert(array[0])}

Answer (score 0):

`loadProductEditForm(${prds})` will expand to
 `loadProductEditForm("248,NORFLOX 200 MG,22")` so perhaps you want
 `loadProductEditForm(prds)` if your function needs an array

```js
var prds = ["248", "NORFLOX 200 MG", "22"]

console.log(`${prds}`)

console.log(prds)
```